# System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<dynamic> exception on Html.PagedListPager

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, pagedlist

When im trying to use my aspx file

```
 @using PagedList.Mvc;
 ...
 @Html.PagedListPager(ViewBag.test, page => Url.Action("Test", new { page })).
```

I'll get this error message

```
'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<dynamic>' has no applicable method named 'PagedListPager' but appears to have an extension method by that name. Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched. Consider casting the dynamic arguments or calling the extension method without the extension method syntax.
```

My .cs file the code look like this

```
    using PagedList;
    private List<Quality> Qualitys()
    {
        List<Quality> Qualitys = new List<Quality>()
        {
            new Quality(){ID=1,Name="All Qualitys"},
            new Quality(){ID=2,Name="1"},
            new Quality(){ID=3,Name="2"},
            new Quality(){ID=4,Name="3"},
            new Quality(){ID=5,Name="4"},
            new Quality(){ID=6,Name="5"}
        };

        return Qualitys;
    }

    public ActionResult Test(int? page)
    {
        int pageSize = 3;
        int pageNumber = page ?? 1;

        ViewBag.test = Qualitys().ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize);
        return View();
    }
```

In my ~Views/Web.config file I'll have there.

```
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace="Web" />
  </namespaces>
```

I cant see why Im getting this error, please help.

Comment: have you included the dll/refernce?

Comment: just type cast ur viewbag in pagedlistpager as (String)ViewBag.test

Comment: The dll should be added, I got PagedList and PagedList.Mvc under my references. Allso that cast dident work.

Comment: Try `@Html.PagedListPager((IPagedList)ViewBag.test, page...` (you need  to cast the viewbag property to the required type)

Comment: It solved to problem! But ist ViewBag.test already a type of IPagedList?

Comment: Yes but you need to cast it so the helper knows what type it is. I'll post as answer so it can be accepted. (note prefix the username - in my case @Stephen - see site help)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to cast dynamic properties (in this case `ViewBag.test`) to the required type. it should be

```
@Html.PagedListPager((IPagedList)ViewBag.test, page => Url.Action("Test", new { page }))
```